# How does the mysqli_fetch_assoc function work?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have one question about mysqli_fetch_assoc in a while loop.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM category ";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
    $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];

    echo $cat_id . " " . $cat_title  ."<br>";
}
```

So, how does `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` work?

So it loops one row at a time from `$results` and stores that information in `$row` until it there is no row to return?

And this  `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` in while loop iterations is this " array(some rows that it got from $result) "?

`$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` is same as `$row = array(all rows from $result that are gathered by mysqli_fetch_assoc)` ?

And that means `$row` is actually an array, and every time it loops the information is not overwriten by new instead it is added?

Comment: That’s essentially correct.

Comment: Pro tip: You can read documentation **for free** for most PHP functions. Using the manual is faster and more reliable than posting to Stack Overflow. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php says: "*Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows.*"

Comment: Have you tried reading the docs and trying to print out the contents of $row in every loop?

Comment: Not really, I sometimes get lost in those documentations, I just like getting answer from human since I am a newbie. Anyway, thanks. :)

Comment: @JayBlanchard that should have been posted as an answer, IMHO. (lol). just kidding of course ;-)

Comment: So you all want to say that what I wrote is true? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` function, PHP is placing the data from the database into an associative array. You can then pull the data out of the array inside of the loop.

Since there is no incrementation to tell the loop when to stop, the while loop takes care of that. So you could read it like so:

While the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` has more records, keep looping. When it runs out, stop.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest explanation is,

When you run [`mysqli_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries `mysqli_query()` will return a `mysqli_result` object which contains data from the database.

---

- [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) - Fetch a result row(one row from the `mysqli_result` object) as an associative array at each time it called and moves the internal pointer to the next. `$row` is used to store that associative array containing **data of single row getting from the `mysqli_result` object**'

you can retrieve data belongs to that raw by using `$row['column_name']`

- The `while` loop does the calling of `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` over and over. After one row is fetched, it goes to the next one and so on till it reaches the end of the object and returns `NULL`, which means `false` and `breaks` the `while` loop.

Comment: "*The while loop does the moving between rows.*" This is not true. The while loop simply calls the same function over and over again. `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` internally loops the result by moving to the next row each time it is called.

Answer (score 1):

> Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows. - [from PHP manual on `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Whenever you call `get_result()` or `mysqli_query()` you will receive a `mysqli_result` object. This object contains the data fetched from the MySQL database server. The data from SQL is returned to PHP in rows. The purpose of `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` is to fetch a row from this object and move an internal pointer to the next row. Next time you call this method on the same object it will fetch a second row and move the pointer to the next row. Once a pointer moves beyond the last row this function will keep on returning `NULL`.

The values in each of the returned arrays correspond to a single row from the MySQL result set. The values are stored as an associative array. Each key is a column name from the SQL.

The purpose of the while loop is to simply call the same function over and over again until it returns `NULL`.

Bear in mind that using `while` loop is not the best approach. It is better to simply use `foreach`.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM category ";

$result = $connection->query($query);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
    $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];

    echo $cat_id . " " . $cat_title  ."<br>";
}
```